# How do I search for files using C# on a windows OS

Tags: c#, search, visual-studio-2005

I have a csv file with file names and I need to search for those filenames in a particular directory. I can read thru a csv file and get all the filenames but would like to know how can I search for those files.

Any pointers would be would of great help

Comment: Do you need to search subdirectories, or simply check a single directory for your file names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy, there are many different ways you can do this. I prefer the "exists" method if I am just trying to find out if the files are there.

```
string SearchDirectory = "C:\\SomeDirectory\\";
List<String> FilesToSearch = new List<string>();
//Populate FilesToSearch from your csv...
foreach (String CurrentFileToSearch in FilesToSearch)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(SearchDirectory + TargetFileName))
    {
        //Do Something!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about trying following code snippet.

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, fileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 3):

[System.IO.Directory.Getfiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx) will give you a list of files in a particular directory.  If you need to so more intensive searching. You may want to use the [windows indexing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266517%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).